# Drupal site menu overlay stuck in Chrome Browser when scrolling down

Tags: theming

I noticed a strange behavior in my drupal Portal when using Chrome. There is an overlay at the top of the page. In Chrome, that overlay gets “stuck” on the page and you can’t easily get rid of it, and it starts constantly flickering. If I refresh its fine and when I scroll down the problem appears again.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Please find the attached screenshot here:

[image]

```
enter code here
```

.fixed#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 18px 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.95);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
style.css?onmqdt:859

## header {

```
z-index: 99;
padding-top: 40px;
background-color: #fff;
```

}

Comment: Hello! This doesn't look like the work of the overlay module. Is it a custom overlay?

Comment: Hi, it's custom overlay, but its working fine in IE, Firefox browsers. only stucks in Crome browser.

Comment: Ok. Then its probably a CSS issue. Can you post the CSS for the overlay?

Comment: .fixed#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 18px 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.95);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
style.css?onmqdt:859
#header {
    z-index: 99;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added these four lines of code to style.css file
position: fixed;
        /* apply these 4 lines only for chrome browser */
        -bracket-:hack[;
        position: sticky;
        position: -ms-sticky;
    ];

and reduce the speed in sticky.js file from 300 to 1.
i have done these. now problem is resloved.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without being able to inspect it, the `z-index` on `#header` won't work unless `position` is set to something other than `static` (the default value).

Try setting `#header` to be `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` whichever is more appropriate and see if that helps, or at least helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: i changed to position: relative & absolute, but it didn't worked. any other suggestions ? Thanks Wes Ruvalcaba for the reply.